# "Web application could not be started. Uninitialized constant Users (NameError)"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, capistrano, passenger

Everything in my application was working fine before I implemented authentications by Facebook and Google.

The application is hosted in Amazon EC2 and I use Capistrano to deploy it. After I tried to deploy the new code, it ends up with this error. The things are working good in local, the problem happens in production only.

Error Details:

```
Web application could not be started.

uninitialized constant Users (NameError)
  /home/ubuntu/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.0/lib/ruby/2.2.0/tsort.rb:226:in `block in tsort_each'
  /home/ubuntu/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.0/lib/ruby/2.2.0/tsort.rb:348:in `block (2 levels) in each_strongly_connected_component'
  /home/ubuntu/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.0/lib/ruby/2.2.0/tsort.rb:429:in `each_strongly_connected_component_from'
  /home/ubuntu/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.0/lib/ruby/2.2.0/tsort.rb:347:in `block in each_strongly_connected_component'
  /home/ubuntu/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.0/lib/ruby/2.2.0/tsort.rb:345:in `each'
  /home/ubuntu/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.0/lib/ruby/2.2.0/tsort.rb:345:in `call'
  /home/ubuntu/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.0/lib/ruby/2.2.0/tsort.rb:345:in `each_strongly_connected_component'
  /home/ubuntu/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.0/lib/ruby/2.2.0/tsort.rb:224:in `tsort_each'
  /home/ubuntu/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.0/lib/ruby/2.2.0/tsort.rb:203:in `tsort_each'
```

Capistrano deployment completes successfully without errors.

Code in authentications_controller.rb is

```
class Users::AuthenticationsController < Devise::AuthenticationsController

def index
  @authentications = current_user.authentications if current_user
end

def create
  auth = request.env["rack.auth"]
  current_user.authentications.find_or_create_by_provider_and_uid(auth['provider'], auth['uid'])
  flash[:success] = "Authentication successful."
  redirect_to authentications_url
end

def destroy
  @authentication = current_user.authentications.find(params[:id])
  @authentication.destroy
  flash[:success] = "Successfully destroyed authentication."
  redirect_to authentications_url
end
end
```

Comment: Please format your code and errors properly

Comment: Done. Thanks for informing.

Comment: Can you also paste your code from authentications_controller.rb please

Comment: Added the authentications_controller.rb code...

Comment: Devise does not have an authentications controller. Try deleting this file and using the default devise controllers?

Answer (score 0):

If the class is `Users::AuthenticationsController`, then its path should be `app/controllers/users/authentications_controller.rb`

Comment: I tried that one too. But in this case also the same error appears just the error changes to :
uninitialized constant Users (NameError)
  /opt/app/sellzie.com/releases/20150212065828/app/controllers/Users/authentications_controller.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'

Both of them work for the authentication in local. But in production none works.

Answer (score 0):

Devise does not have an authentications controller. Try deleting this file and using the default devise controllers.